# Pointer to object created in parameter

Tags: c++

I have a class called `Rectangle` which holds two pointers to objects of the class `Point2D`.

```cpp
class Rectangle: public GeoObjekt
{
private:
    Point2D* lu;
    Point2D* ro;
public:
    Rectangle(Point2D lu, Point2D ro);
}

Rectangle::Rectangle(Point2D lu, Point2D ro) {
    this->lu = &lu;
    this->ro = &ro;
}
```

To create an object of this class, I call the following line:

```cpp
Rectangle rectangle(Point2D(0, 0), Point2D(2, 1));
```

The constructor is working fine, but when I try to access `Point2D* lu;` or `Point2D* ro;`, I get an access violation exception:

> Exception thrown at 0xFEDC8589 in Rectangle.exe: 0xC00005: Access violation while executing at position 0xFEDC8589.

I checked it with the debugger and the values inside `Point2D* lu;` or `Point2D* ro;` are completely different from the values they initially had. They change after leaving the constructor.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Note: The line `Rectangle rectangle(Point2D(0, 0), Point2D(2, 1));` should remain as it is.

Comment: Do you understand what a dangling pointer is?

Comment: _"... have a class called rectangle which holds to pointers..."_ hold `Point2D` instead.

Comment: Quick tip: use pointers as little as possible in modern C++. Never use `operator new` except in _placement new_ expressions and always prefer smart pointers and containers such as `std::vector` and `std::array` to raw pointers and C arrays. Do this constantly and you will notice your programs will basically never crash, unless you do something really bad. Nowadays in C++17 and C++20 I mostly use pointers as a replacement for `std::optional<T&>` (which is not legal).

Comment: @mcilloni ok. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the members `lu` and `ro` to be `Point2D` instead of `Point2D*`.

The `Point2D`s you supplied in the constructor are destroyed on the next line, so your pointers end up pointing at nothing (dangling pointers).

Comment: This worked. I am a bit confused why this is a dangling pointer but I will research for it. Thank you!

Comment: @slow You are passing *temporary* objects to the constructor, and then saving pointers to the objects. The objects are destroyed automatically after the constructor exits, thus leaving the pointers pointing at freed memory. That is why the pointers are dangling. What Camwin suggests is to get rid of the pointers altogether, thus having the constructor *make copies* of the temporary objects instead.

Comment: Another reason for this change: you really do want to store the corners themselves (coordinates), not just where they happen to be located in memory (pointers).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I thought only the access will be 'deleted' but the object themselve will still exist. Thank you very much!

Comment: @slow you should read up about [Lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) and [Scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope). In the statement `Rectangle rectangle(Point2D(0, 0), Point2D(2, 1));` the two `Point2D` objects go out of scope, ending their lifetimes and thus are destroyed, when the statement that is calling `rectangle()` is finished (ie, when `;` is reached).